# How to check if all inputs are not empty with JQuery in order to show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where, after the user answer every question in it, he clicks a button and a div is shown. How can I show a div when all inputs are filled?

- The div can ONLY be shown after EVERY FIELD is filled!!
- The div is shown when the user clicks the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that you have two input fields, and a button and a hidden div.
Now you can do the following

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="password">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
<div class="showDiv hidden"></div>
<script>
    var totalInputLength = $('input').length;
    $('button').click(function(){
        var validInputs = $('input').filter((key,value) => v.value).length;
        if (validInputs == totalInputLength) {
            $('.showDiv').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('.showDiv').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what you've tried, but I'd start with something like this. Loop over the inputs of the form, and then check if they're empty. Then you can show or hide your div in a few different ways. This may help get you started.

```
$(function(){
    $("form#formID :input").each(function(){
           var input = $(this);
           if (!input.val()){ 
              alert('empty input');
              return false;
           }  
    });
    //do some logic
    $('#target_div).hide();
})
```